# Sending email to git culprits or committer who broke the build with ext-email plugin

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, email-ext, jenkins-build-flow

I have jenkins setup where POST HOOKS trigger a SCM polling job and the polling job triggers build flow job and build flow job calls various other jobs.

The git plugin mentions that we can use GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL and GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL environment variables, but i get the value as null. Since I am unable to set the commiter's email here, I am not able to propagate the email address to all other jobs which doesn't have git information.

Another post mentions about sending email to culprits with ext-email plugin, but that doesn't work too.

Any ideas on how to get the git committer info or culprit information ?